# Вставка текста из Word и его автоматическое форматирование

Tags: jquery, javascript

Необходимо сделать так, чтоб пользователь скопировал текст из MSWord и вставил его в поле ввода.

При этом:

1. После вставки (Ctrl+V), каждый абзац автоматически обрамлялся в `<li></li>` (вроде с этим справился, но непонятно почему выводится пустой `<li></li>` в конце вставленного текста).
2. Пользователь мог отредактировать введённый текст прям в этом же поле (сейчас это происходит крайне не корректно).
3. Пользователь смог бы вставить текст из MSWord (на данный момент это сделать можно, но только если вставим текст взамен существующего, а не в добавление к нему).

Вот что налепил:

```
$('#input').bind('input', function () {
    $(this).val('<li>' + $(this).val().replace(/\r?\n/g, '</li>\n<li>') + '</li>');
});
```

Много что перепробовал, ничё не помогло.

фиддл: http://jsfiddle.net/kutepovfedor/7VtGs/2/

Comment: думал сделать что-то подобное:

var isCtrl = false;
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
    if(e.which  == 17) {isCtrl=false;}
    }).keydown(function (e) {
        if(e.which == 17) {isCtrl=true;}
     if(e.which == 86 && isCtrl == true) {
            $(this).val('<li>' + $(this).val().replace(/\r?\n/g, '</li>\n<li>') + '</li>');
     }
});

но получается не совсем то и работает не корректно

http://jsfiddle.net/kutepovfedor/7VtGs/3/

Comment: а чем вам событие paste не подходит ?

Comment: Пробовал событие paste, проблема следующая:

$('#input').bind('paste', function () {
    alert($(this).val());
});

алерт выводит строку, которая уже была в поле, а новой (вставленной) там нет, алерт покажет её при следующем событии вставки. 

Возможно есть способ сделать так, чтоб в алерт летел сразу вставленный текст, в дополнение к существующему...

Comment: Так, покопался на свежую голову, вот что получилось:

http://jsfiddle.net/kutepovfedor/7VtGs/4/

Но теперь при каждой вставке к уже существующему тексту применяется та же замена символов. 
Необходимо чтоб форматирование применялось только к вставляемому тексту.

Кстати в IE не работает =(